# Non-$p$-torsion difference of $p$-torsion elements in a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

I have a relatively simple question. For $p$ odd, does there exist a non-abelian $p$-group such that for every pair of non-commuting $p$-torsion elements $g$,$h$ their difference $g^{-1}h$ is not $p$-torsion?

As a kind of motivation, we ran a search in GAP for 3-groups and on our sample the following trichotomy occurs:

- The group is abelian, or
- all $3$-torsion elements commute, or
- there exist $g,h$ that are $3$-torsion and do not commute, and $g^{-1}h$ is $3$-torsion.

Note: I previously asked it on MathOverflow, but the question was in the wrong form (twice). So I restated it and decided to ask here firstly.

EDIT: Made a mistake again, thank you for pointing that out. The difference is NOT supposed to be $p$-torsion.

EDIT2: By $p$-torsion here I mean "of order $p$".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144811/discussion-on-question-by-igor-sikora-non-p-torsion-difference-of-p-torsion); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have a proof that such a group does not exist. Still the proof might be wrong, or too long, or unclear - please advise in case.

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $G$ is such a group. The subgroup of $G$ generated by its elements of order $p$ still satisfies the hypothesis, so  we may assume that $G$ is generated by its elements of order $p$.

As noted in the comments, if all elements of $G$ of order $p$ commute  pairwise, then the assumption holds trivially. Since we have assumed that $G$ is generated by its elements of order $p$, we may thus assume that $G$ is non-abelian.

Consider the terms $Z_{i}(G)$ of the upper central series of $G$, and the terms $\gamma_{i}(G)$ of the lower central series.

We first show that there is $t \in Z_{2}(G) \setminus Z(G)$ of order $p$.

Since $G$ is non-abelian, and it is generated by its elements of order $p$, the set
$$
\{ j : j > 1 \text{, and there is $x \in Z_{j}(G) \setminus Z_{j-1}(G)$ of order $p$}\}
$$
is non-empty. Let $i$ be its minimum.

Suppose by way of contradiction that $i > 2$. Let $x \in Z_{i}(G) \setminus Z_{i-1}(G)$ have order $p$. Let $k$ be greatest such that there is $u \in \gamma_{k}(G)$ such that $[x, u] = x^{-1} u^{-1} x u \notin Z(G)$. (This is where we use the fact that $i > 2$.) In particular we have $[x, [x, u]] \in Z(G)$, as $[x, u] \in \gamma_{k+1}(G)$, so that the group $H = \langle x, [x, u] \rangle$ has nilpotence class at most two. Clearly $x^{u} = u^{-1} x u = x [x, u] \in H$. Thus in $H$ we have
$$
[x, u]^{p}
=
(x^{-1} x^{u})^{p}
=
x^{-p} (x^{p})^{u} [x^{u}, x]^{\binom{p}{2}}
=
[[x, u], x]^{\binom{p}{2}}
=
[[x, u], x^{\binom{p}{2}}]
=
1,
$$
where we have used the facts that $[x^{u}, x] = [[x, u], x] \in Z(G)$, and $p > 2$, so that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{2}$.
Thus $[x, u]$ is an element of order $p$ in a $Z_{j}(G)$, for some $i > j > 1$, contradicting the definition of $i$.

So consider $t \in Z_{2}(G) \setminus Z(G)$ of order $p$.  As $t \notin Z(G)$, and $G$ is generated by elements of order $p$, there is $x \in G$ of order $p$ which does not commute with $t$. But in the group $K = \langle x, t \rangle$ of class two we now have
$$
(x t)^{p} = x^{p} t^{p} [t, x]^{\binom{p}{2}} = [t, x^{\binom{p}{2}}] = 1,
$$
once more as $[t, x] \in Z(G)$ and $p > 2$.

Comment: On first readthrough it seems good. I was trying, on and off, something similar working with descending induction on the lower central series, but hadn't sat down to write it carefully, so this seems reasonable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! However, I have a question. How do you obtain the equality $(x^{-1}x^u)^p=x^{-p}(x^p)^u[x^u,x]^{\binom{p}{2}}$?

Comment: @IgorSikora it's a standard equality in group of nilpotence class at most two.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Is it that in such a group a commutator of two elements is a central element?

Comment: @IgorSikora In a nilpotent group of class two, every commutator is central.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting the answer, but I needed to understand it thoroughly, which took some time, as I am not fluent in group theory :) Thank you, that's a very nice proof!

Comment: @IgorSikora, no problem, thanks!